# What happened if I set Interval less than 1 second in asp:Timer?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've just created queuing system with `ASP.Net` `Webforms`, using `asp:Timer` and `asp:UpdatePanel` to partial refresh the page. I set `asp:Timer` `Interval` to "100" which is means 0.1 second. After every partial page refresh, the page called Stored Procedures which is sometimes didn't run well. Are there any best practices of my problem and what's the impact on my system if I set `Interval` less than 1 second?

Comment: *...some of processes didn't run well...* What exactly does that mean?  Please post your code.

Comment: How likely is it to give a good experince if all your users' browsers are constantly flooding your server with HTTP requests for page content to refresh the dispay.. If you want a workflow like that, that's designed for it, use Blazor

Comment: @squillman actually the page call stored procedure after partial page refresh which is sometimes don't run well. I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'll considered it for using Blazor, Thank you

Comment: My point is "sometimes doesn't run well" is not an adequate description of your problem.  That can mean any number of things.  Be specific when you ask a question.  Give errors that you receive (or indicate that you don't get any), describe performance problems, show metrics that you've gathered, if it's in SQL Server show the query and an execution plan.  Help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a timer which doesn't have enough time to complete before the next tick, a solution is to manually call the next tick inside the timer callback itself

```vb
ReadOnly interval As Integer = 100
ReadOnly minIntervalBetweenCalls As Integer = 0
Private ReadOnly Timer2 As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf Timer2_Tick, Nothing, interval, -1)

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(state As Object)
    Dim nextRunTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval)
    ' run processes
    Timer2.Change(Math.Max(nextRunTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Milliseconds, minIntervalBetweenCalls ), -1)
End Sub
```

The math ensures the next tick will either happen 100ms after the start of the current tick, or immediately after the current tick, accommodating ticks taking longer than 100ms.

Comment: Note: this should answer your question, but the comments below your question posing an additional question to you about your fundamental design should be seriously considered!